# Corda jar launching: Address already in use: bind error

Tags: java, kotlin, jar, corda

I have perfectly working Corda app in Kotlin - it launches and works normally when launched from IDE

But when I try to build it as jar file, it crashes with the following error

```
    INFO: Booting SSHD 
    INFO 11, 2019 8:28:27 PM org.crsh.ssh.SSHPlugin init 
    INFO: Booting SSHD 
    INFO 11, 2019 8:28:28 PM org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle init 
    INFO: About to start CRaSSHD 
    INFO 11, 2019 8:28:28 PM org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle init 
    INFO: About to start CRaSSHD 
    INFO 11, 2019 8:28:28 PM org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle init 
    SEVERE: Could not start CRaSSHD 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind 
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) 
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor.bind(Nio2Acceptor.java:63) 
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor.bind(Nio2Acceptor.java:87) 
    at org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer.start(SshServer.java:325) 
    at org.crsh.ssh.term.SSHLifeCycle.init(SSHLifeCycle.java:182) 
    at org.crsh.ssh.SSHPlugin.init(SSHPlugin.java:192) 
    at org.crsh.plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins(PluginManager.java:83) 
    at org.crsh.plugin.PluginContext.start(PluginContext.java:327) 
    at org.crsh.plugin.PluginLifeCycle.start(PluginLifeCycle.java:104) 
    at net.corda.node.shell.InteractiveShell$ShellLifecycle.start(InteractiveShell.kt:181) 
    at net.corda.node.shell.InteractiveShell.startShell(InteractiveShell.kt:118) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.startShell(AbstractNode.kt:297) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:262) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:700) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) 
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:699) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:347) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:207) 
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:361) 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:805) 
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:767) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119) 
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$Sche..(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have only one node launched and seemingly no processes can interfere with program's execution (it, again, works fine when launched from an IDE)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide the code that causes the error instead of the exception backtrace. Also the operating system you are using may be important.

Comment: `val rpcUsers = listOf(User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL")))

driver(DriverParameters(startNodesInProcess = true, waitForAllNodesToFinish = true)) {

startNode(providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyG", "New York", "US"), rpcUsers = rpcUsers).getOrThrow()

}` 

The code in question. It should launch a node, but fails somewhere inside, I suppose.

The operating system is Windows 10

Comment: Did you realize that you *can* edit the question? Code formats much better in questions (and answers) than in comments. And: *If it's part of the question, add it to the question!*

Answer (score 0):

`Address already in use` probably means that another program is using this port. Make sure there's only 1 instance of your code running at the same time. Also, try to change the port it is using or find the program using this port

Comment: The difficult part is that I can't check what port the program is trying to use because it fails internally in Corda library function. And ports we are setting manually can be used because it works when we run it from the IDE

Comment: Then it means you have to find the port Corda uses, not much you can do here I'm afraid